# Comparing two letters returns false, but their unicode character is the same

Tags: javascript, unicode

(What kind of sorcery is this?)

I have two characters which looks the same, but when doing a comparison they are different:

```
console.log("i" === "i︆") // false
```

Then I compared their code which tell me it's the same, which is even stranger:

```
console.log("i".charCodeAt(0), "i︆".charCodeAt(0)) // 105 105
```

But finally I found the problem, the length of both characters is not the same:

```
console.log("i".length, "i︆".length) // 1 2
```

I'm wondering:

- Is there any explanation why the length of both characters is not the same?
- Is there a way to convert both characters so the comparison works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one has an invisble character (65030) at position 1.

```js
 console.log("i︆".charCodeAt(0), "i︆".charCodeAt(1))
```

Which means they're not 'strictly' equal.

Comment: It will false even on non strict quality

Comment: To clean the string, I used `str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, '')` (which remove any non unicode character)

Answer (score 1):

The second character has an invisible character with code 65030 which belongs to "VARIATION SELECTOR" block of the Unicode standard.
When I copied your example, I got the same but when you type it, it will give TRUE.
Result with the copy paste:

```
console.log("i".charCodeAt(0),"i".charCodeAt(1),"i︆".charCodeAt(0),"i︆".charCodeAt(1),"i︆".charCodeAt(2))
105 NaN 105 65030 NaN
```